# other languages URL for silverstripe 4

Tags: php, silverstripe

I use the following configuration in my `config.yml` in version 3 of Silverstripe:

```
URLSegmentFilter:
    default_allow_multibyte: true`
```

Is there a different configuration for version 4 of Silverstripe?

Answer (score 3):

Comparing the documentation between [version 3](https://api.silverstripe.org/3/URLSegmentFilter.html) and [version 4](https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/View/Parsers/URLSegmentFilter.html)—it appears that there have been significant API changes.

`URLSegmentFilter` was defined in the global namespace in version 3, and is now defined as `SilverStripe\View\Parsers\URLSegmentFilter`.

Reading the [configuration docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/getting_started/directory_structure/), it appears you should change your config.yml file to account for this namespace update:

```
SilverStripe\View\Parsers\URLSegmentFilter: 
    default_allow_multibyte: true
```

Comment: The URL changes in the admin panel, but when i try the URL it's going to the Page not found (404)

Comment: @Misagh90 This could be a different error—it's hard to advise further without further information. Can you update your question with additional information?